# Update data when having UNIQUE Constraint

Tags: database, unique

I am having a simple scores table for HTML5 game with columns: name, email and score. Email value should be a unique value, but when the same users play the game again to better their scores, the score should be updated for that user. Now it returns an error because of the unique value. How should I create a table that will update the data?

The table I have created so far:

```
CREATE TABLE `scores` (
     `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `name` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL,
     `email` VARCHAR( 320 ) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
     `score` INT NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY ( `id` )
     ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use an insert statement with an `on duplicate key` clause:

```sql
INSERT INTO scores (name, email, score)
VALUES ('some_name', 'some_email', 123) -- Values from your application
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
score = CASE VALUES(score) > score THEN VALUES(score) ELSE score END
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I must admit I have troubles inserting this example. I am new to this and I guess I chose a hard task for my school project...

For the PHP I have this code to send the data to the database: https://jsfiddle.net/skxgrd6u/

Answer (score 0):

It is not about your create table query, it is about your insert query.

Use a try catch method to update the unique value

```
try
{
// inserting the line
}
catch (exception)
{
// Drop the row with that unique value
// inserting the same line which you have added in "try" section
}
```